# Como executar evento logo após o $('div').load(url)?

Tags: jquery, eventos

Quero saber como fazer um `$('#div-search').on('load', ()=>{alert('carregou');});`

Tenho uma `div` em que há diversos  `$('#div-search').load(url)` no código.
contudo agora preciso realizar uma série de validações após o carregamento do mesmo.

já tentei os seguintes testes:

```
$('#div-search').on('load', ()=>{alert('carregou');});
$('#div-search').on('ready', ()=>{alert('carregou');});
$('#div-search').ready( ()=>{alert('carregou');});
```

e nenhum deles surtiu efeito.

> **P:***"mas pq tu não faz ´$('#div-search').load(url,()=>{alert('carregou');})*´?"
>   **R:**
>       *1.* Por que não quero ter que procurar em todo código as chamadas;
>       *2.* Por que nem sempre é fixo *$('#div-search')*, muitas vezes é uma variável *$(seletorId)* e, além de ser mais difícil de encontrar, eu teria que fazer um IF;

Comment: Detalhe melhor o que você precisa, do jeito que a pergunta foi formulada não da entender o que você precisa.

Comment: Quero saber como fazer um `()=>{alert('carregou');}` depois de terminar de carregar `$().load('google.com');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`.ajaxComplete`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), que será executado sempre que uma requisição ajax completar.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log('carregou')
});
```

Se precisar diferenciar requisições, use os parametros passados para o callback. Toda vez que uma requisição ajax é completa, um objeto de evento, o objeto XMLHttpRequest e o objeto de configuração usado na criação da requisição são passados para a função que usou no `.ajaxComplete`. Por exemplo, se quiser restringir o callback para responder apenas para uma URL específica:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "google.com" ) {
    console.log( "Carregou. O resultado é" + xhr.responseText );
  }
});
```

**Nota**:

- A partir da versão 1.9 do jQuery, a chamada do método `.ajaxComplete()` *precisa* ser feita a partir do `document`.
- Se `$.ajax()`ou `$.ajaxSetup()` forem chamados com o valor `false` attribuído à opção `global`, o método `.ajaxComplete()` não será disparado.

Comment: funcionou para o a primeira chamada e depois não funcionou mais

Comment: @HagaHood Está restringindo por url ou usando como o primeiro exemplo?

Comment: primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Pode ser o `alert`influenciando no fluxo assíncrono. Tente usar `console.log` no lugar do `alert`.

Comment: é algum bug na p@#$ da pagina, criei uma pagina somente com 1 div e 3 botões fazendo o load e funcionou como eu queria. valew.